# Swift 5: Socket IO integration and send data

Tags: ios, socket.io, swift5

I am very new to Socket IO. My requirement is to connect to a socket with URL and join a specific room with some unique identifier string value like "join_id". Once I successfully joined that room once successfully joined in that room I need to send some JSON to that room and wait for an acknowledgement.

var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: myURL)!, config: [ .log(true), .compress ])

```
    let socket = manager.defaultSocket
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect){(data,ack) in
        print("connected")
        socket.emit("test", "Hi Server!")
    }
```

And listener is,

```
    socket.on("testresult") { [weak self] (data,ack) in
        print(data)
        print(data.description)
    }
    socket.connect()
```

As per the server team, I need to join a room by passing a string value (join_id). And once I got successful acknowledgement I need to send JSON and wait for the acknowledgement for confirmation on data receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join Room specific press on emit data

```
self.socketIOClient.emit("join_id", with: "154") /*Like Random id generate*/
let jsonDic = ["room":driver_id,"userId":"\(userID)",
                "quoteId":quote_id,"isRequest":"1"] /* Json Data send to server */
self.socketIOClient.emit("sendRequestToDriver",jsonDic)
```

Get json Respone

```
let manager:SocketManager!
let socketIOClient: SocketIOClient!
manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: ServerAPI.SocketURL)!, 
     config: [.log(true), .compress])
socketIOClient = manager.defaultSocket
 self.socketIOClient?.on("orderRequestUpdateByDriver") { ( dataArray, ack) -> Void in
 let dict = dataArray[0] as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
  Print(dict)
}
socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: .error) { (data, eck) in
    print(data)
    print("socket error")
 }
    
socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { (data, eck) in
    print(data)
    print("socket disconnect")
 }
    
 socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: SocketClientEvent.reconnect) { (data, eck) in
     print(data)
     print("socket reconnect")
 }
socketIOClient.connect()
```